# Crear permisos en Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Hola soy nuevo con Django, quisiera saber cómo puedo crear permisos con Django, porque los que crea automático no me hacen falta, y necesito crear otros que no tienen relacion con las tablas sino con el acceso a las opciones del menú, hace tiempo ví algo parecido pero no me acuerdo cómo lo hicieron, sólo se que cuando daban sincronizar automáticamente se insertaban los permisos me pueden explicar cómo se crea un modelo para la gestión de permisos e insertarlos automáticamente, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#Creando_usuarios_y_grupos

Comment: Los permisos adicionales de pueden crear desde el modelo pero para ello deberías tener un modelo dónde gestiones tu menú

Comment: Hola @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas , cómo es que puedo crear ése modelo y con los permisos predefinidos, Porque la documentación que encontré es modelos normales, esto es nuevo para mi

Comment: te he puesto u n ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuación te pongo un ejemplo de como crear un permiso desde un modelo, Se puede crear uno o varios luego este permiso se lo asignas al usuario que quieras desde admin

```
class NombreModelo(models.Model):
    ....
    ....

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('nombre_permiso', 'Descripcion del permiso'),
                       (.....),  )
```